# How do i make this graph bigger?

Tags: python, matplotlib

how can I make this graph bigger so the dates don't jumble together on the bottom? When I try to plt.figure it gives me <Figure size 720x360 with 0 Axes>. I also want it so the y axis is also larger.

[image]

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 5)) 
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(merge_df.Date, merge_df.hourlywage, color="red", marker="o")
ax.set_xlabel("year",fontsize=10)
ax.set_ylabel("Hourly wage",color="red",fontsize=14)
ax2=ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(merge_df.Date, merge_df.GDP,color="blue",marker="o")
ax2.set_ylabel("GDP",color="blue",fontsize=14)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plt.xticks(rotation=70)` - to make the xticks rotated at 70 degree to the axis and the ticks will all be visible instead of cluttering together.

Comment: But that's not what OP asked, right? "How do i make this graph bigger?" Where does OP ask about xticks?

Comment: the problem is "so the dates don't jumble together on the bottom" - OP is approaching the problem in a wrong way.

Comment: Maybe OP doesn't want to rotate the xticklabels though. Aren't you assuming something?

Comment: Well we can increase the ```figsize(x, y)``` - a larger value for x and then OP has to scroll sideways for reading everything ... I was looking at easier way to solve the problem ... if it helps OP I would be happy